# Add 3 business days to the new date

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add the new date with 3 business days. For example if user select Wednesday then it should display Monday. For Thursday, it should display Tuesday and for Friday should display Wednesday. Below is the code:

JQUERY:

```
    $(function () {

    $('.one').datepicker();

    $('#data').on('change', '.one', function (date) {                
        var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 3);
            $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);

    });

    $('.two').datepicker();

    });
```

Comment: Gee, did we see this yesterday as well.  BTW what is a business day?  And what is you question?

Comment: Business days means working days. Monday to Friday

Comment: How to add 3 working days with the new date. date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 3 business days); something like this.

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: Instead of adding default 3 date from the input date, i just want to add 3 working days from the input date. For example if user select Wednesday then it should display Monday. For Thursday, it should display Tuesday and for Friday should display Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where if you can clearly describe the situation, you can easily write logic.

How many calendar days away is 3 business days, if the initial day is:

- Monday?
- Tuesday?
- Wednesday?
- Thursday?
- Friday?
- Saturday?
- Sunday?

Answer that, and you'll come up with logic like this:

```
var day = date2.getDay();
if (day == 3 /* wed */ || day == 4 /* thur */ || day == 5 /* fri */) {
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 5); // 3 days + 2 weekend days!
} else if (day == 6 /* sat */) {
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 4); // 3 days + 1 weekend day!
} else { /* either sun, mon, or tue */
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 3); // 3 days
}
```

Comment: Monday - Thursday, Tuesday - Friday, Wednesday - Monday, Thursday - Tuesday, Friday - Wednesday

Comment: So if you know that, code that!  Monday: 3 days, Tuesday: 3 days, Wednesday: 5 days, Thursday: 5 days, Friday: 5 days.  Don't forget Saturday and Sunday.  At this point, you know what to tell the program to do.  The first step to programming anything is to explain it so clearly that even a computer could do it...

Comment: +1 for `The first step to programming anything is to explain it so clearly that even a computer could do it`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$(function () {

    $('.one').datepicker();

    $('#data').on('change', '.one', function (date) {                
        var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 3);
            var day2=date2.getDay(); //0=Sun, 1=Mon, .., 6=Sat
            if(day2==0 || day2==6){
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+2);
            }
            $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('.two').datepicker('setDate', date2);

    });

    $('.two').datepicker();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var date=new Date();
cday=date.getDay();
var addDays;
switch(cday){
    case 0: // case sunday
    case 6: // case saturday
        addDays=4;break;
    case 3: // case wednesday
    case 4: // case thursday
    case 5: // case friday
        addDays=5;break;
    default:
        addDays=3;// for Monday and Tuesday
}
alert('New date: \n'+new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+addDays)));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afKxx/1/)